# How to translate title text of component?

Tags: react-native, internationalization, translation, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

How can I translate the title text dynamically with i18n tools such as `i18next`.

Currently I am passing in the title like so:

```
Settings.options = {
  topBar: {
    title: {
      text: 'Settings',
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Do you want to update the navigation title after language change has occurred? or use i18next in your project ?

Comment: The initial start of the app should translate the text correctly. It is more of a general question. For the app otherwise I am currently using i18next but it could really be any translation library.

Comment: I used react-native-localization with V3 and just passed the reference to the string and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

```
// get t function somewhere, i.e.
const t = i18next.t:

Settings.options = {
  topBar: {
    title: {
      text: t('settings.title'),
    },
  },
};
```

On language change make sure this code part is executed again... so t() function can evaluate again.